# Es correcto usar la palabra "Apóstola" para referirse a una mujer que es "Apóstol"?

Tags: gramática

Quisiera saber si es correcto aplicar el genero femenino a un sustantivo como "apóstol" dejando la palabra como "apóstola" que se entendería es una mujer que actúa como "apóstol". Es similar al caso de la palabra "adolescente", que no es posible decir *"adolescenta"*. Gracias.

Comment: Opino que la palabra _adolescenta_ no es correcto, su uso es: _El_ adolescente o _la_ adolescente.
¿Podría proporcionar mas información acerca del "posible" uso de apóstola?

Comment: cito a la cuenta de la RAE de facebook " #RAEconsultas Hay adjetivos de dos terminaciones, como «rojo, -ja», «amarillo, -lla» o «listo, -ta», y otros de una sola terminacion valida para el masculino y para el femenino como «maron», «azul» o «imbecil» "

Answer (score 8):

[Apóstol](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=xHnv3oJGnDXX2HjwhwSM) designa a evangelizadores/propagadores de doctrinas de ambos sexos.

De acuerdo a las reglas de [formación del femenino en profesiones, cargos, títulos o actividades humanas](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Profesiones_en_g%C3%A9nero_femenino#Formaci.C3.B3n_del_femenino_en_profesiones.2C_cargos.2C_t.C3.ADtulos_o_actividades_humanas.5B2.5D):

> Los sustantivos terminados en –l o –z funcionan para ambos géneros.

Por lo tanto `apóstol` como "profesión" funcionaría para ambos géneros. "Apóstola" sería incorrecto.

**Nota**: Aunque decimos

> el/la cónsul, el/la corresponsal, el/la timonel, el/la capataz, el/la portavoz.
>
> el juez/la juez, el aprendiz/la aprendiz, el concejal/la concejal, el bedel/la bedel.

algunos han desarrollado formas en femenino terminadas en "–a":

> la jueza, la aprendiza, la concejala, la bedela

La recomendación para estos casos es usar formas ya asentadas y de uso mayoritario. Gracias a @Gorpik por mencionar esta situación en los comentarios.

Por cierto, me he dado una vuelta por la red a ver si podía encontrar algún ejemplo "oficial" para validar el uso de "apóstol" con un femenino, pero no hay muchos ejemplos de apóstoles mujer. Yo sólo he podido encontrar uno, y parece que incluso todavía se pone en duda si era hombre o mujer, debido a [las traducciones del griego](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120809152702AARW881) del evangelio de San Pablo: [la apóstol Junia](http://www.feadulta.com/es/buscadoravanzado/item/1545-junia-ap%C3%B3stol-ilustre.html).

Comment: Lo poco que he encontrado hasta el momento referente a la palabra _apostola_ (excluída la tilde) hace mención además de la apóstol Junia a _María Magadalena_ también conocida como _apostola apostolorum_ "apóstol de apóstoles en latín". [fuente](http://www.monografias.com/trabajos53/maria-magdalena/maria-magdalena.shtml).

Comment: +1. De todos modos, los femeninos de palabras que hasta ahora solo se han usado para personas masculinas no tienen reglas del todo fijas, por la falta de uso hasta hace poco. Así, en España la palabra *presidente* tiende a variar a *presidenta* para el femenino, pero otras parecidas como *disidente* no varían. Y, dentro de la regla que mencionas, para el femenino de *juez* se usan tanto *juez* como *jueza* (yo prefiero *juez*, aunque solo sea porque la palabra más parecida que hay en castellano, *nuez*, es femenina).

Comment: Y me dejaba *adolescente*, el ejemplo mencionado en la pregunta, que tampoco varía.

Comment: @Gorpik, tienes razón, por eso intenté encontrar un ejemplo "oficial" para un apóstol mujer. Supongo que se crean nuevos cada día, debido a nuevos usos y la corrección política: (típico "los españoles y las españolas" que usaría un político en un discurso).

Comment: Corrección política o lo que sea: cuando una palabra se empieza usar (muchas palabras referentes a profesiones en femenino, actualmente), tiene una evolución hasta que se fija en los hablantes. Por cierto, el uso de "señoras y señores" o "damas y caballeros" para dirigirse a un público tiene tradición; eso del "españoles y españolas" no es tan nuevo como parece (aunque a mí me suene demasiado forzado).

Comment: Portavoz es un poco diferente... es una construcción de tipo verbo (3.a persona singular) más sustantivo.   Estas palabras son siempre invariables excepto cuando el sustantivo es incontable (y por tanto, singular), en tal caso, se admiten una versión plural.

Answer (score 3):

El sustantivo «apóstol», a pesar de estar recogido en el DRAE solo como masculino, se usa como palabra del género común. Por lo tanto, se dice *la apóstol* y es frecuente escuchar la palabra *mujer* prepuesta o *femenina* pospuesta.

No obstante, también existe la palabra «apóstolo», hoy poco usado, que sí tendría una forma femenina con *-a*. Y, de hecho, en una búsqueda de libros publicados en español surgen algunos ejemplos de esta palabra de autores religiosos.

Así que como resumen:

- la forma femenina de **apóstol** es **apóstol**
- la forma **apóstola** existe, pero es la forma femenina de **apóstolo**, variante desusada de *apóstol*