# Uso de "fenómeno" en femenino

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adjetivos, sustantivos

Según la RAE:

> **[fenómeno](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HlH0iLR)**
>
> 4. m. coloq. Persona sobresaliente en su línea.

Este sustantivo se usa siempre en su forma masculina, lo que me causa dudas cuando es aplicado a mujeres. ¿Cuál sería correcto?

- Esa mujer es un fenómeno.
- Esa mujer es una fenómeno.

Lo gracioso es que la palabra también se puede usar como adjetivo:

> 6. adj. coloq. Muy bueno, magnífico, sensacional. *Es un tío fenómeno.*

En este caso no parece que haya que usar siempre el masculino, luego se podría decir *una tía fenómena*. Casos así hay en el CREA:

> *[...] Nino se lo agradecía y opinaba que tenía una mujer fenómena, comprensiva, una gran compañera.*
>
> Jorge Andrade, "Un solo dios verdadero", 1993 (Argentina).

Si existe "fenómena" como femenino en su uso como adjetivo, ¿no se podría decir *esa mujer es una fenómena*? A fin de cuentas, también existe algún que otro caso en la prensa escrita:

> *Cámaras de Canal 9, de TV3, de TVE, de Antena 3, de Tele 5, emisoras de radio, todas las televisiones retratando el origen de la última fenómena del tenis español.*
>
> La Vanguardia, 02/01/1995. España.

¿Es correcto este uso? He visto casos de adjetivos en los que existen ambas formas (por ejemplo: *campesino/a*, *conductor/a*) dado que la RAE especifica que se usan también como sustantivo). ¿Podría ser "fenómena" uno de estos casos? Si no, ¿qué diferencia a "fenómena" de "campesina" o "conductora"?

Comment: En mi opinión, el adjetivo debería variar en género, no hay motivo para que no sea así. Sin embargo, en el sustantivo tenemos un caso parecido al de la palabra *estrella*; podemos decir que *Brad Pitt es una estrella del cine* con toda normalidad. No olvidemos que en castellano usamos muchas veces sustantivos masculinos para referirnos a mujeres y femeninos para varones. Pero bueno, el uso lo dirá.

Comment: *Fenómeno* empezó como un sustantivo cualquier y masculino.  Luego adquirió un uso para referir a las personas, así podríamos verlo como digamos, «desastre» (*este hombre / esta mujer es un desastre*).  Luego seguramente pasó a ser sustantivo yuxtapuesto como *piloto* o *clave*, pero llegó a flexionarse completamente (para mí, por ejemplo, *piloto* es invariable — *proyectos piloto* — y *clave* todavía está en flujo —para mí vale tanto *palabras clave* como *palabras claves*).

Comment: Ya con el uso adjetival, podríamos imaginar la frase «una mujer fenómena» rápidamente acortándose en *una fenómena*, sin que «ella es un fenómena» se queda como opción inválida.

Comment: Es un uso emergente. Al menos por estos lados nunca oigo *fenómeno* como adjetivo (para eso ya tenemos el invariante *fenomenal*). Como sustantivo es *un fenómeno* sin dudar en todos los casos.

Answer (score 2):

Usted lo ha preguntado mientras esa forma se está estableciendo. Como ya verificó, aunque hay algunos usos la forma femenina, aún no la reconoce la DRAE. Pues si quiere uno escribir en ámbito formal, ocupará lo masculino; y si le gusta más el neologismo femenino, entonces allí está.

En [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=campesina%2Cconductora%2Cfen%C3%B3mena&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccampesina%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcampesina%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCampesina%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCAMPESINA%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cconductora%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bconductora%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BConductora%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfen%C3%B3mena%3B%2Cc0) uno verá que "conductora" y "campesina" existían mucho antes de "fenómena".

Answer (score -1):

El uso de "fenómeno" que siempre he conocido es para referirse a cosas, circunstancias, sucesos, características, verbos, pensamientos, sentimientos, y a todo lo que se conoce, incluso la existencia es un fenómeno. Podremos denominar como fenómeno incluso a la manera en que una persona mueve sus ojos para voltear a fijar un punto o como podemos interpretar los símbolos en conjunto a palabras y luego a pensamientos.
A mi parecer es correcto usarla a como se nos venga en gana, sin embargo, es incorrecto decir "fenómena", lo cual ya sería otra palabra a la que le deberíamos encontrar o asignar significado.

Creo que es como decir "zapatos para hombre" y después querer decir "zapatas para mujer".

Hay demasiados términos que no tienen, ni deben tener, femenino y masculino, y hay que usarlos como se deben, en los contextos y oraciones adecuadas.

Comment: "Zapata" es a "zapato" lo que "caballa" es a "caballo". No es un femenino "mal formado" es una palabra con significado propio. Es correcto preguntarse si existe "fenomena", igual que consideramos otras formas como ["jueza" o "presidenta"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11882/5481) y razonarlo como usos de otros vocablos como ["apóstola](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/11836/5481)

Comment: Bueno. Al final de cuentas, nosotros hacemos el lenguaje.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Es un poco como lo que decía Pérez-Reverte hace poco sobre que la RAE es más "notario que policía" al incluir el "iros" como imperativo de ir. Si la gente empieza a usar "fenómena" como femenino de "fenómeno" (y termina por aceptarse, como "jueza" o "presidenta") no podemos decir que sea una palabra distinta o mal formada (o tal vez sí, como es el caso de "apostola"?) Por eso incluí los enlaces. Habrá que ver en base a qué argumentamos cada cosa. Yo no esto de acuerdo en que deba significar a la fuerza otra cosa distinta (salvo por el género).

Comment: A lo que yo quiero hacer referencia es que "fenómeno" es un termino como "aire", no es necesario ponerle una "a" al final, para decir que nos referimos a una fémina, eso es todo, es una sóla cosa. :)